# Android stock themes for dark background

Tags: android, android-theme

My Android application has a dark action bar and a dark background for the rest of the activity. A theme such as `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` works well for the dark action bar but not for dark activity background. For example, the circle for radio button is drawn in black and is barely visible.

I am wondering if there are any themes in Android that cater to dark backgrounds. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theme.Holo and Theme.Material are dark themes.

Comment: Thank you. Theme.Holo worked. Although Theme.Material works too and is a bit better, I cannot use it my minimum API level is 18.